# My Python code is not display the second choice when it IS entered. Why is this happening?

Tags: python

My Python code is acting weird, I have two choices, Yes and No. In that Yes choice it's also possible to enter y which I did by using the or statement. But the only thing that is wrong with it is that it only displays the first IF statement option. I have no idea what's going on. Here's my code, and my output:

Code:

```
print("Je bent in een donkere grot en je gaat dood. Wil je dood?")
dieornot = input()
dieornot = dieornot.lower()
if dieornot == "ja" or "y":
    print("Je eet een koekje en gaat zomaar dood.")
elif dieornot == "n" or "nee":
    print("Pech, je gaat toch dood.")
```

Output:

> > > 

```
Je bent in een donkere grot en je gaat dood. Wil je dood?
nee
Je eet een koekje en gaat zomaar dood.
```

Sorry, it's dutch but you should see what I mean.
Any help with this is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
if dieornot == "ja" or "y":
```

you want

```
if dieornot == "ja" or dieornot == "y":
```

Even better, I would recommend:

```
if dieornot in ("ja", "y"):
```

As that makes this mistake less likely and it's more concise.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This worked! Only weird thing is, why does this work with elif then?

Comment: @user2291141 For an explanation, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18540973/330057](my answer). I was going to put it in a comment here, but it got a little long so I threw it in an answer.

Comment: @user2291141: hmm the else if is wrong also. you should change both of them. it only works by accident =P.

Answer (score 2):

proper would be

```
 if dieornot == 'ja' or dieornot == 'y':
```

the way you had it: `x == y or z`

would evaluate to `(x==y) or z`

you want `(x==y) or (x==z)`

Comment: +1, just to add on this, alternative solutions: `x in [y, z]`, `x in (y, z)`.

Comment: ... `x in {y, z}` (set; useful for very large numbers of items to test with).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because your if statement is broken up into two parts:

if (dieornot == "ja") or ("y")

the first part (dieornot == "ja") is false. But the second part ("y") is true, because "y" is not null. You aren't comparing "y" to anything, so it's just assuming you mean "Does "y" exist?" and naturally, being a constant, it does exist.

Any of the [previously mentioned fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18540913/330057) will work.